# Existing rule redirect to new url rule

Tags: .htaccess

My old URL structure is like domain.com/product-name-etc-pid-001.html which I had the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule (.*)-pid-(.*)\.html$ p.php?n=$1&pid=$2
```

For my new structure the URLs are domain.com/products/product-name-etc/001

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ p.php?pid=$2 [NC,L]
```

Now I want all of the old URLs to be pointed to their new locations permanently.

```
   Redirect 301 /(.*)-pid-(.*)\.html$ ^compare/$1/$2/?$
```

I have been experimenting and come up with the above code, as expected it did not work and gave a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used old rule and made slight modification and come with the following solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pid-(.*)\.html$ /compare/$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how your solution solves the problem. This allows future visitors to this question to understand how this code snippet solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-pid-([^.]+)\.html$ /products/$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /p.php?n=$1&pid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried the first rule as I have the second one in place already however it just shows a 404 error.

Comment: Which URL throws 404?

Comment: I have found the solution.